# Sync SQLITe / Core Data with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, core-data, nsxmlparser

I want to sync Data between a MySQL WebServer and a mobile Database Core Data on the iPhone. On my last project I wrote php files who creates XML files with the content of the MySQL Data. And the iOS Project parsed the XML files to sync the data. To transmit the data from the iPhone to the MySQL Server I wrote a second php file. This connected to the MySQL database and execute the statement.

What do you think is it a good way to sync data between the iOS Application and the MySQL Web Server? Do you have any Ideas to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good plan. If you follow the plist specifications or use JSON you can convert the data even more easily (without `NSXMLParser`) into your custom classes and insert them into the Core Data store.

Make sure to devise a scheme where you only have to send/receive incremental changes.